# Is time dilated for objects that make a close orbit around (massive) bodies?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, time-dilation

I understand that, according to general relativity, matter warps space-time in such a way that the 3-dimensional projection [in space] of the geodesic of an object subject to no forces looks like massive bodies attract our test object. And we call this gravity.

I also understand that matter also “slows down time”: meaning that the projection into time looks like time for the test object is dilated. For example, time for objects standing on earth goes “slower” than time in satellites.

Question is, is time dilated for satellites even if just a little bit? Or are satellites unaffected because they are in free fall and their condition is equivalent to floating in outer space? [contrary to an object standing on earth which is being accelerated in space-time]

Thanks all !

Comment: Time dilation of orbiting satellites (e.g. the GPS system) is perhaps one of the most commonplace set-piece examples of any first General Relativity course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, objects in orbit are affected by gravitational time dilation. Time dilation is not directly connected with acceleration (this is the [clock postulate](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/clock.html)); it is only indirectly connected insofar as acceleration (may) change a clock's speed. In the case of a clock in orbit, the clock experiences the same gravitational time dilation as an observer in a fixed tower at the same height would; however, it also experiences a velocity related time dilation that the observer in the tower would not.

Comment: Whether you postulate it or derive it, what matters is whether the "clock postulate" agrees with experiment. And it does, at least in the tests performed so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the satellite does experience time dilation. Keep in mind that it is not merely the object, but the empty space itself that is subject to time dilation, even if there is no clock.  Any object in that space will take on the surrounding time dilation.

I like to think of time dilation like a weather low pressure system, and the clock as a balloon.  The balloon will expand or contract as viewed by a distant observer as it moves through the weather low. But inside the weather low pressure, the balloon maintains the same relative pressure.